# is it feasible to learn networking on virtual machines setup?

Tags: networking, virtualization, webserver, network-adapter

i'm on the pace to begin my self study about networking, i only have one machine which is a notebook PC with 4gb of RAM, Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.53GHz, and planning to install virtual machines on it to learn about howto setup computer networks, run/configure servers (eg, domain controller, webserver, fileserver, pfsense etc.), network architectures, some other network admin task and possibly some ip/tcp concepts , would this be possible to learn on a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, but this question seems way too broad to be answerable here.